# How I can get the Index of select in php

Tags: php

```
<span>Level</span><br>
 <select name="exp" id="exp" required>
   <option disabled selected hidden>Choose your level</option>
   <option>without exp</option>
   <option>up to 1 month</option>
   <option>up to 3 months</option>
   <option>up to 6 months</option>
   <option>1 year or more</option>
 </select>
```

PHP:

```
$exp = "";      

if(!empty($_POST)){
   $exp = $_POST['exp'];     //here I get only the value??
   calcularIMC($exp);    
}

function calcularIMC($exp){            // comparisons I want to do
    if($exp == "INDEX 0"){ ...... }   // how I can get the value to do this comparations?
    if($exp >= "INDEX 1"){ ...... }
}
```

For the test I did the variable `$exp` is storing in the form of string. I wonder how I can get the index to make the comparisons made in the above example.

How can I get the index of select?

Comment: Add a value to each `option`, `<option value='0'>without exp</option>` and so.

Comment: and to make comparisons, how I do? eXAMPLE: `if($exp>"index[1]")`??

Comment: in your code, $exp will be the value of the selected option, so you can `if ($exp == 0) {...whatever...}`

Comment: Thank you guy! It's amazing how I always have problems with simple things. Already complex things, I do with super ease. I made a mega script that says the ideal type of skateboard for any athlete and had difficulties in this bullshit. It happens with you? Or has happened?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set values for your options, then those would be the values submitting to your server.

```
 <select name="exp" id="exp" required>
   <option disabled selected hidden>Choose your level</option>
   <option value="0">without exp</option>
...
 </select>
```

Comment: It is strange that people tend to skip this important step.  Bad direction in the tutorials I guess.

Comment: Yea maybe... @durbnpoisn

Comment: and to make comparisons, how I do? eXAMPLE: `if($exp>"index[1]")`??

Comment: I found tutoriais.. But I couldn't find something specific to what I want.